# tqdm - why printing multiple lines to start?

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

so I'm using tqdm package to output a progress bar. The console does support carriage return `\r`. I could not find a solution in other posts.

It starts by printing the first few iterations on new lines As you can see below, it prints 4 new lines, then finally on the fifth, the overwrite to a single line kicks in.

Why is this happening? Is there anyway or ideas on how I can prevent this so it'll overwrite from the start?

Here's the output:

```
  0%|          | 0/240 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  0%|          | 1/240 [00:01<04:59,  1.25s/it]
  1%|          | 2/240 [00:02<04:43,  1.19s/it]
  1%|▏         | 3/240 [00:03<04:44,  1.20s/it]
  13%|█▎        | 32/240 [00:31<03:09,  1.10it/s]
```

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Do you have an example? We need some code to look at.